# Big O Notation for the given code fragments

Tags: java, time-complexity, big-o

I am looking for some help regarding big O notation. The goal is to give the order of growth for the given code fragments.

```
int sum = 0
for (int k = n; k > 0; k/=2 )
  for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    sum++;
```

For this code fragment I got (N logN). The first for loop is logN and the second for loop is N.

```
int sum = 0
for (int i = 1; i < n; i *= 2 )
  for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    sum++;
```

I had some trouble on this one. The first for loop is logN, however the second for loop is where I get stuck. The second for loop in dependent on the first for loop. I'm not sure how to show that in big N notation.

```
int sum = 0
for (int i = 1; i < n; i *= 2 )
  for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    sum++;
```

The first for loop is logN. The second for loop is N. So this is (N)?

I am struggling with this and would appreciate some help. Thank you

Comment: The last example is still N * logN. You have to perform N operations log N times, ergo, you get N * log N.

Answer (score 1):

1. You are correct on the first code fragment: O(n*log n).
2. In the second code fragment, `j` loops up to `i`, which can goes as high as `n - 1`, so that `j` `for` loop is O(n) *by itself*.  But let's examine what happens.

   - n = 16
   - i = 1 The inner loop runs 1 time.
   - i = 2 The inner loop runs 2 times.
   - i = 4 The inner loop runs 4 times.
   - i = 8 The inner loop runs 8 times.
   - n = 17
   - i = 1 The inner loop runs 1 time.
   - i = 2 The inner loop runs 2 times.
   - i = 4 The inner loop runs 4 times.
   - i = 8 The inner loop runs 8 times.
   - i = 16 The inner loop runs 16 times.

The counts of the loops is

```
1 + 2 + 4 + ... + 2^x = 2^(x+1) - 1
```

where x is the power of 2 before `n`.  This `2^(x+1)` could be as high as 2n, so the overall complexity is O(n), dropping the constant "2".

3. The third code fragment is similar to the second code fragment; only that `j` goes all the way to `n` each time.  The complexity here is O(n*log n).

Comment: Wouldn't the second inner run to `i-1` each time thereby making it `n(n+1)/2`? Sorry, not `n` due to the outer; that would have to be adjusted for the log.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils That is incorrect, but my original analysis of the second fragment was incorrect too.  I've corrected it now.